# Qt.CursorName vs Qt.CursorShape.CursorName

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I started using MyPy today and many errors were based on the cursors I use inside my project.

The error was for example:

`Type[Qt] has no attribute "ForbiddenCursor" [attr-defined](line:col)`

After looking in the documentation I found out that the correct namespace is `Qt.CursorShape.CursorName`. Now I am wondering why every tutorial/example uses the shorthand (`Qt.CursorName`) and which one should be used in general?

Is there any common sense?

Comment: Because they are correct. The new naming convention was introduced with [PySide6.3](//doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html) as the full-python enum support replaced the old int based flag mode, similarly to what PyQt6 did, with the "migration" process unofficially introduced in the latest PyQt5 releases (which didn't use actual enums yet, but began support for the namespace change).

Comment: So the examples which use Qt.CursorName are just "old" and use the "Forgiveness Mode". But mypy is correct in encouraging me to use the full enum name. thanks

Comment: PyQt6 dropped support for short forms. Anyway, what about answering your own question?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html#forgiveness-mode-and-type-hints), PySide 6.3 replaces the Shiboken enums with the Python variants. To allow a smooth transition and not break legacy code, you should always use `Qt.CursorShape.CursorName` for new code, but `Qt.CursorName` is still applicable. Also, it is perfectly fine for the IDE to report `Qt.CursorName` as an error, as you should if you can switch to the new approach.